Why cannot co_yield from std::ranges::elements_of copy the elements?
The default behaviour of std::generator<T> is the same as std::generator<T&&>, which means that both its reference type and yielded type are T&&. However, the promise type of this generator has a yield_value overload that also takes a const T& argument and stores a copy of that argument inside the awaitable (this copy is then available to the outside world as a T&& reference). Thus, the following is fine (here, I use the int type just as an example):
std::generator<int> works_ok() {
    int x = 1;
    co_yield 1;  // OK, takes int&&
    co_yield x;  // OK, creates a copy of x inside the awaitable
}

I would expect a similar behaviour when co_yielding using the std::ranges::elements_of wrapper, but this doesn't work:
std::generator<int> fails() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
    co_yield std::ranges::elements_of(v);
}

The problem is in the constraint that std::ranges::range_reference_t<std::vector<int>> (which is int&) is not convertible to yielded (which is int&&). Why can't there be an overload that deals with this situation in the same way co_yielding a single lvalue is dealt with? And what is the best workaround here? I have thought about v | std::views::as_rvalue, but that might not be what I want (the vector might be const or the type T might be something else than int and I don't want it to be moved from). Another option is to replace the last line with for (auto x : v) co_yield std::move(x);, but that seems to partially defeat the purpose of elements_of. Or is elements_of only supposed to be used with rvalue-producing ranges?

You can explicitly specify the generator's second template parameter (its value_type) as int:
std::generator<int, int> works_ok() {
  std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
  co_yield std::ranges::elements_of(v);
}

Or change the first template parameter into an lvalue reference, i.e.,
int&:
std::generator<int&> works_ok() {
  std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
  co_yield std::ranges::elements_of(v);
}


Sure, but what if I do want the behaviour of std::generator<T>, i.e. that rvalues are still yielded as T&&?

(Of course, that makes no sense for an int; imagine a different type there…)

@NikolaBenes Using v | as_ravlue is fine IMO. I don't think there is a more simple way to do it.

Well, it's not completely fine. What if I don't want the elements of the vector moved from? (Again, ignore the int and imagine something resource-holding.)

Plus, it doesn't work if the vector is const.

"What if I don't want the elements of the vector moved from?" as_rvalue does not move the element, it just transforms it to an rvalue. And if you don't want to move elements, what's the point of rvalue-producing ranges?

First of all, it doesn't work if the vector is const. Second, the outside might move the element if it gets a rvalue reference to it. Third, the point is to have a generator in which I can yield both lvalues and rvalues, and the correct thing happens (rvalues passed as-is, lvalues copied to the awaitable). This works with co_yield single_value, but it doesn't with elements_of.

To put it differently, ideally, co_yield elements_of{ rng }; should have the semantics of for (auto&& elem : rng) co_yield std::forward<decltype(elem)>(elem); and I am wondering what prevents this behaviour.

"To put it differently, ideally, ..." std::ranges::elements_of(v) gives you a range whose elements are lvalues since vector::iterator::operator* always produces lvalues, which is consistent with for (auto&& elem : rng) co_yield std::forward<decltype(elem)>(elem);. There is no so-called "prevents".

"First of all, it doesn't work if the vector is const." Then you should return std::generator<const int&>.

There is a “prevents”. I can write for (auto&& elem : v) co_yield std::forward<decltype(elem)>(elem); in the function above and it compiles (the values are copied to the awaitable). I cannot write co_yield std::ranges::elements_of(v); in the same place, because it doesn't compile.

"I can write for (auto&& elem : v) co_yield std::forward<decltype(elem)>(elem); in the function above and it compiles." Which function?

The second one in my original question. Instead of the co_yield elements_of…

Oh, I finally know what you are talking about. Yes, it does look like a defect.

The convertible_to constraint seems too restrictive; we should just require that static_cast<yielded>(*i) be well-formed. Demo._

This doesn't seem right; you are casting int& to int&& (and not creating the copy in the awaitable). Notably, the demo fails to compile if the vector is const. The for cycle works if the vector is const.

I think we need a second overload for yield_value(elements_of(range)) similar to the second overload for yield_value(single_value). But that might not work If the range is a different generator… I think I am starting to see the reason (for not having this second overload in the standard) now.

"Notably, the demo fails to compile if the vector is const" When switch to for-loop, the const vector will compile, but a SIGSEGV crush will occur. Demo. Not sure if this is expected behavior or a bug.

Anyway, if you think this could be considered a standard defect, you can file an LWG issue.

The SIGSEGV only occurs with gcc trunk. With gcc 14.2 it works fine.

Thats bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=117231
